# Calling a function that return db model in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

this is my implementation class

```
@Service
public class QuizServiceImp implements QuizService {

    @Autowired
    QuizCategoryRepository quizCategoryRepository;

    @Override
    public List<QuizCategory> findAll() {
        List<QuizCategory> list = new ArrayList();
        list=(List<QuizCategory>)quizCategoryRepository.findAll();
        return list;
    }

}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@page import="java.util.List"%> 
<%@page import="com.quizV1.service.QuizServiceImp"%> 
<%@page import="com.quizV1.model.QuizCategory"%> 

<%@ taglib uri = "java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %> 
<%-- <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> --%> 

<% QuizServiceImp ob=new QuizServiceImp(); List<QuizCategory> list=ob.findAll(); %>
```

i want to call this funtion in jsp page

Comment: this is my jsp page code  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
     <%@page import="com.quizV1.service.QuizServiceImp"%>
     <%@page import="com.quizV1.model.QuizCategory"%>
 <%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
 <%-- <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> --%>
 <%

    QuizServiceImp ob=new QuizServiceImp();
     List<QuizCategory> list=ob.findAll();
 %>  but this return error

Comment: Please do not post code in comments.  Nobody can read that.  Instead, edit the question and put in there.  Specify what the error is, and where it occurred

Comment: Please, don't. The whole point of MVC is that the controller is supposed to provide the model to the view. And the whole point of dependency injection is that the framework injects the dependencies that you need: you don't create them using `new`. Read a basic guide about Spring MVC to understand how you're supposed to use it. And forget that scriptlets exist. You should never use them.

Comment: Also, what's the point of creating a new ArrayList and to assign it to the variable list if the next instruction reassigns a different list to that same variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Spring to inject dependencies into `QuizServiceImp` so you cannot use constructor to initialize variables of `QuizServiceImp` because in this case Spring doesn't know then you've created new instance and it needs to inject dependencies.

To fix it you need to get bean from Spring context.

```
<%@page import="org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils"%>

<%
  WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
        .getWebApplicationContext(application);
  QuizService service = context.getBean(QuizeService.class);
%>
```